# Dynamic path in Powershell workflow

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a variable to specify a path in a Powershell workflow, more specifically in a `InlineScript` of a Workflow.

To add more context: I'm writing a deployment script for my application. I need to restart the computer and continue my script. I achieved this part by registering a Scheduled task which is launching another script at startup.

So I have a first script A which registers some jobs like:

```
workflow installXming{
    Suspend-Workflow
    InlineScript{
        $scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
        Import-Module "$scriptPath\modules\_install_Xming_fonts.ps1";
        xming_fonts
    }
}
```

This script reboot the computer and call a second script B which resumes the suspended jobs:

```
$jobs = Get-Job -state Suspended
$resumedJobs = $jobs | resume-job -wait
$resumedJobs | wait-job
```

When I get the output of my job, I got an error on my `$scriptPath` variable.

I know I can't use the `$PSScriptRoot` in a Powershell workflow.

Is there any way I can use "persitent" variable to store some value or is there a way to use a variable to store the path of my script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

I simply make my workflow take an argument which is the current path of the script.

```
workflow myWorkflow{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)]
    [string] $scriptPath
    )
    Suspend-Workflow
    InlineScript{
         Import-Module "$Using:scriptPath\modules\_myMoldule.ps1";
         # DoStuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above one what I observed:

**Import-Module** works only in case of modules . So in your case, I can see that you are importing a **.ps1** which seems wrong. It should be a **.psm1**

Secondly, *Powershell workflows* have their own *scope*. To get the resultant value from the variable you have to use **$Using:**

Below is the modification of your script and corresponding to that a sample script for your reference.

***Your Script modified***

```
  workflow installXming
{
  Suspend-Workflow
  $scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
  InlineScript{
    Import-Module "$Using:scriptPath\modules\_install_Xming_fonts.psm1"; ## Assuming it as .psm1 file
    xming_fonts
            }
}
```

***Sample Script:***

```
Workflow Stop-MyService
{
    $ServiceName = "MyService"

    $Output = InlineScript {
        $Service = Get-Service -Name $Using:ServiceName
        $Service.Stop()
        $Service
    }

    $Output.Name
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I use `Import-Module` with a ps1 just for debug now, I should fix it later :)
I tried your suggestion but i got the same error:
`Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.`

Comment: Because  I believe it is not able to get the path. Import-module won't be able to bind the path with any of the ps1 file. Please get a .psm1 file or just rename it to psm1 and try it. I dont think you will face this issue again.

Comment: Ok I created a module according to your answer but I got the same error.

Comment: which psversion you are in ? could you please output the path in the console and see if at all it is sending the value inside the inline or not

Comment: I'm using Powershell 4 and it seems the problem come from this line:
`$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition` which cannot be output in the console (I got the null path error)

Comment: OO. So thats the issue. NOw what I suggest you to hardcode one complete path and test it . In that way you can assure that the script is working fine, then you can sort out the path issue. Make sense right ..?